# How to set up routes from a url provided by an API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to display Twilio recordings

The url is

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Recordings/{RecordingSid}
```

The date (2010-04-01) is referenced by = `@recording.DateCreated`
`{AccountSid}` = `@recording.AccountSid`
`{RecordingSid}` = `@recording.Sid`

How would I create the routes?
get ...

Also how would I display these urls in a list:

```
<% @recordings.each do |recording| %>
 <li>
  <%= link_to recording? %>
 </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In config/routes.rb:

```
date_rx = /^(19|20)\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/

get '/:date/Accounts/:account_sid/Recordings/:recording_sid',
  to: 'mycontroller#myaction', as: 'recording',
  constraints: { date: date_rx, account_sid: /\d+/, recording_sid: /\d+/ }
```

In the view:

```
<% @recordings.each do |recording| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to recording_path(recording.date, recording.AccountSid, 
          recording.RecordingSid) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```